# Can I set the default browser differently for different websites?

Tags: browser, default-applications

I have the following browsers on my phone:

- stock
- Dolphin Mini
- Opera Mobile
- Firefox

I don't want to set a catch-all default because some pages render better on some browsers than on others.

When I click on a link on a non-browser app (e.g. google search or google reader) it asks me which browser to choose (as expected).  Can I set a default browser for some pages and a different default for others?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an app called "Browser Auto Selector" which looks like it will allow you to associate a domain with a browser.
Here is the link to the page on AppBrain for the app, http://www.appbrain.com/app/browser-auto-selector-free/info.usamimi.kfc9.superakiraman.browserchooser_free