# How do I set a system-wide default browser?

Tags: settings, default-applications

I seem to have the opposite problem from [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/can-i-set-the-default-browser-differently-for-different-websites): I'd like to set a single browser (probably the default one) to open every website. What happens at the moment is that *every single link* pops up a menu asking if I want to open it in the default browser, or in Firefox, or in Firefox Beta, or with Phone to Chrome. It makes browsing the web pretty frustrating...

Samsung Galaxy Note, Gingerbread.

Comment: I believe that some browsers, like Dolphin, have an option within the app to make it the default for everything.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't mentioned I'm assuming you haven't tried this.

You've to select '**Use by default for this action.**'.

[image: Source: Lifehacker]

Comment: Yes - but that only seems to set a default for that particular URL (or that server, maybe) The next link that differs slightly (eg, m.blah.com instead of www.blah.com) pops up the choice again.

Comment: @SteveBennett That's strange behavior. It should pop up for a couple different types of things (files vs links, for example) but not for individual URIs or sites.

Comment: It will pop up for every type of link that can be handled by different apps, e.g. HTTP, HTTPS, YouTube, Google+, any other app that is registered to handle certain types of links.  Note also that any time one of these apps is updated, the default setting will be lost and you will have to choose again.

Comment: Ah, is that what's going on. I find I'm constantly having to set these defaults - so frequently it's not even worthwhile. Many apps seems to update every week or two, so that would explain it.

Comment: I've removed the browsers and other apps that I found I rarely use, and also update apps in batches, rather than every time one has an update.   This has cut down significantly on the number of times I see this dialog.

Answer (score 3):

See if [Default App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) works for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 4.0 you can (starting at home)

1. press the menu button
2. select search
3. type in: default browser
4. select the thing that it finds and the rest should be similar to another answer here and fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running ICS just go into your settings, choose app associations, choose web urls, and set what browser you want to open by default for any and all web urls that are opened within any app.

Comment: I don't see anything like "App associations" in settings? Touchwiz btw.