# Non default browser for specific web page

Tags: dolphin-browser

I have bought my 8 year old a Nexus 7 (lucky boy!). As some of you may know Flash is not available for Jelly Bean so I had to do a bit of a hack using Dolphin browser so he can go to certain Flash powered websites (moshimonsters.com). I want the default browser to still be Chrome so I can use Funamo Parental Control to monitor his web use. Is it possible to create a shortcut/widget/bookmark to the site in question but specifying Dolphin as the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This related question might have a solution: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8674/can-i-set-the-default-browser-differently-for-different-websites

Comment: See MacroDroid or Tasker heading here: [How do I easily create an image/button on my Android home screen which links to a website?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/122946) You would get an idea how to make a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

It is doable, but you cannot do this without 3rd party application, because by default shortcuts or bookmarks (as available in the system features) do not hold such information. I am not able to name any app that would do this, as I never personally needed this, but I am certain they do exist as it is not technically complicated, as most likely you are not the only one with such needs. All it needs to be done is to create a shortcut, which would launch this 3rd party app being a "proxy" and said app would then call explicitly specified application handing your URL to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about a shortcut but a simple widget should be good enough for your needs. While I have not tried this myself here is how I would start:

1. Write a simple widget to put on the home screen. Be prepared to send in a new intent as soon as the widget is started up
2. Open the Dolphin browser while having your device connected to ADB. Notice the intent that is being sent by the ActivityManager when starting the browser.
3. In your app create a new Intent() and fill it up with the specific component/class name of Dolphin browser and pass in the URL of the site you want to open as data.
   I think the tricky part will be detecting the exact class and component name used by Dolphin browser. The rest of it should be straight forward (I think).