# How to open some app links in a non default browser

Tags: default-applications

This is what I want to achieve (on Android):

I want all links that are not otherwise linked to an app to open in my default browser (Samsung Internet)

This is the default behaviour and how it currently works.

I then want specific types of link to open in Firefox browser. For example, I would like to register youtube.com app links to open in Firefox, not My default browser.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Is there an app I can install that will allow me to set it to open arbitrary app links, and then forward those to another application (in this case, Firefox)

I have found two apps, "better open with" and "open link with" which sort of achieve this by registering themselves as a browser, and if you then set them as the default browser, they then forward all links onwards to the browser of your choice using some form of rules.

What I would like to do is basically the same thing but without having to register another app as the default browser. Instead I want to get only specific app links to open in my non-default browser.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Can I set the default browser differently for different websites?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8674/44325). While it's a very old question, I'm afraid the answer hasn't changed since it's not possible to do this without an additional 3rd-party app because the Android system itself doesn't provide such customization.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've found, you have to disable Chrome in order to not have YouTube open the tab in the YouTube app.

From other people on Android exchange, they've said they could do this on all other apps, except for YouTube.

Comment: While the technicality of this answer is correct, I'm afraid this doesn't really answer the question asked here.